# Bootstrap modal won't show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to get a bootstrap modal to work. In index.php I have a few links that will load the pages PageOne.php and PageTwo.php.

In PageOne.php I'm trying to call a modal with #LinkToModal but the modal won't show. I am using Chrome and when clicking on the button I can't even see something in the console changing.

This is my code:
index.php

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <!-- Javascript -->
        <script src="inc/bootstrap-assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="inc/bootstrap-assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

        <script src="inc/js/functions.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>Home</h2>

        <a href="" id="LinkToPageOne">Link To Page One</a>
        <a href="" id="LinkToPageTwo">Link To Page Two</a>
        <div id="Content">something</div>   

    </body>


<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS -->
</html>
```

PageOne.php

```
<div id="PageOne">
    <button id="LinkToModal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal">Large modal</button>

</div>

<div id="Modal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

functions.js

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LinkToPageOne").click(function () {
        $("#Content").load("inc/content/PageOne.php #PageOne");
        return false;
    });
    $("#LinkToPageTwo").click(function () {
        $("#Content").load("inc/content/PageTwo.php");
        return false;
    });

    $("#LinkToModal").click(function(){
            $("#Modal").modal("show");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are assigning click handler to "#LinkToModal" too soon, when your page hasn't even loaded. 'load' function loads the html inside the "content" div over AJAX. So you should assign the click handler after it has been loaded. 'load' function gives you a call back , in which you can add this handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LinkToPageOne").click(function () {
        $("#Content").load("inc/content/PageOne.php #PageOne",function(){
              $("#LinkToModal").click(function(){
                 $("#Modal").modal("show");

              });
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

> or

You can use '[on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)' function to assign the click handler, which will add it to any dom that gets added after the handler has been assigned. Just remember to assign it on the expecting parent. For e.g. :

```
$("#Content").on('click','#LinkToModal',function(){
            $("#Modal").modal("show");

    });
```

Comment: While the explanation sounds plausible, both the solutions do not work. No modal and no activity in the chrome toolbar console either.

Comment: did you debug to check if atleast the click hander is getting attached or not? Modal not showing could be then due to some other issue, which can be debugged.

Comment: @Shaunak , Yes I'm debugging by putting a alert() on the place where I call my modal. The alert works like it's supposed to but still no modal.

Comment: okay cool.. so we now know that your problem of handlers not getting attached is now fixed. As to why modal doesn't show up , could be result of mis-wired bootstrap. I would suggest, putting that modal HTML directly on the page, and try invoking modal though your global javascript, see if that works....

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("#LinkToModal").click(function(){
            $("#Modal").modal("show");

    });
```

To:

```
$("body").on('click','#LinkToModal',function(){
            $("#Modal").modal("show");

    });
```

Because you are loading your HTML ajax, so you will need to bind the event using [On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Did you mean "...on('click', '#LinkToModal'..."?

Comment: Still no change, it won't show a modal and I can't see anything about it in the chrome console.

Comment: @Joop try to put a break point inside the click event handler, can you? or you can't find the script in the chrome?

Comment: @AmrElgarhy Where the modal is supposed to execute I put in a alert(), to see if it's related to the modal or the way I put in the functions. It turns out that it is the modal, because the alert box is showing when the modal is suposed to be. So the function works, but it doesn't show my modal ...

Answer (score 0):

It is because of fade class. It adds opacity:0 to modal